# When validating an apple receipt with apple

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

To be clear on my question, I am in the process of implementing a iOS IAP receipt validation (consumables) and I was not expecting more then just the item(s) the user 'currently' purchased in the 'current' transaction.

So lets say the user purchases one (1) $0.99USD item that gets them 100 coins I am expecting to see in the receipt using my validation code the one (1) transation detailing the one (1) product they purchased not an array of items from previous purchases which I found out that:

`With iOS 7, Apple started using something they call the “Grand Unified Receipt”. Apps retain one receipt that contains information about the purchase of the app itself, as well as IAPs.`

So my question is if anyone else has an issue with the receipt format and how have everyone been validating the purchases for consumables when the entire user purchase history is always present?

Comment: You can save the transaction id when the user make the purchase and then when you get the JSON info back from apple server, filter the array of by the transaction id you have.

Comment: @Jad, thats is what i am implementing. I will have a node where I store all the transactionId's and if a transactionId is under my list of transactionId's it will be flagged as a duplicate and the user will not be credited the amt of the purchase.